# Openstack recover orphaned instances

Tags: instance, openstack, recover

I'm using Openstack Havana with one compute node based on kvm and a controller node running in a VM.
After a bad hardware failure I got into a situation where the controller is aware of a subset of the instances (preceding a certain date) and completely lost the newer instances. I suppose we had to restart from an older backup instance of the controller.
All the information about the instances is still available on the compute node (disk, xml) and they even still appear in virsh list --all.
Is there a way to just re-import them into the controller? Maybe by sql or some nova command line?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. We solved the issue the rough way. Converting the disk file produced for OpenStack (OS) instances to VDI (thanks qemu-img) we then run the suitable glance command to import the VDI as an image into OS. From the dashboard we then created an instance on that image and reassigned our floating-ip.
Anyone has counter-indications to this?
Thanks.